# Create object from implement Runnable interface in threading - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, class, oop

I'm new in Java and threading.

Is there any different to create an runnable object as `Runnable` and `ThreadState`:

```
class ThreadState implements Runnable {

  public void run() {
    System.out.println("xxxxx");
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Runnable r1 = new ThreadState();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
    t1.start();
  }
}
```

And

```
class ThreadState implements Runnable {

  public void run() {
    System.out.println("xxxxx");
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ThreadState r1 = new ThreadState();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
    t1.start();
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can extend your class from Thread and directly make an object from ThreadState():
class ThreadState extends Thread { 
...
...
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ThreadState r1 = new ThreadState();
    r1.start();
  }

Comment: @IssaKhodadadi – Although you ***can*** do, it is discouraged to extend `Thread` …

Comment: FYI: This question has nothing to do with threads and threading. It's a question about Java's type system and what `interface` means, and you just happened to choose an interface that the `Thread` class cares about for you example. You could have asked about any other interface (e.g., `List<T>`) and any situation in which an object that implements that interface was wanted, and it would be essentially the same question.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `r1` is neither a `Runnable` nor a `ThreadState`.

It is just a reference to an object of that type.

In both cases, with the execution of `new ThreadState()` you create an instance of `ThreadState` that is also an instance of `Runnable`.

As a result, your code snippets are equivalent.

```java
public class ThreadState implements Runnable 
{
  @Override
  public final void run() 
  {
    System.out.println( "xxxxx" );
  }

  public static final void main( String... args ) 
  {
    Runnable r1 = new ThreadState();
    if( r1 instanceof ThreadState ) System.out.println( "r1 is ThreadState" ); // will be printed
    Thread t1 = new Thread( r1 );
    t1.start();
  }
}
```

vs.

```java
public class ThreadState implements Runnable 
{
  @Override
  public final void run() 
  {
    System.out.println( "xxxxx" );
  }
  public static final void main( String... args[] ) 
  {
    ThreadState r1 = new ThreadState();
    if( r1 instanceof Runnable ) System.out.println( "r1 is Runnable" ); // will be printed
    Thread t1 = new Thread( r1 );
    t1.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tquadrat, a follow up question: which one is better to create an object?

Comment: @henrylam, The compiler will generate _exactly_ the same code from either of your two examples, so "which one is better" is a question of _style._ I think that most of my colleagues would say that declaring the variable to be `Runnable` is more stylish because `Runnable` is what it needs to be in the only place where it is used. In more complicated programs, declaring variables with less restrictive types (e.g., `Runnable` instead of `ThreadState`) can often make it easier to _change_ the code in the future.